# controlling a bluetooth hardware remotely by php(control panel website)

Tags: php, bluetooth, estimote, beacon, gimbal

I am having a bluetooth low energy device which broadcasts its signal every 30ms. and I have a website as a control panel to show some devices statistics and to send some commands to the device.

I want to control the intervals between signals that bluetooth broadcasts. make the interval more or less.

In my website I want to have a page for this, so the user can  change this intervals easily(or changing the signal strength)

i know that beacon companies have such control panels. but I do not know the concept that how we can sends commands remotely to a device by php.

if anyone has any idea that can help me speed up the procedure please let me know.